# inheritance logic : PlayerBase and Player scripts childs

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, structure

I need help for my inheritance logic.

This is my project structure : (All script are on "Player" (prefab obj)

```
PlayerBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Some props
    public Color Color {get; set;}

    void Start()
    {
        Color = Color.Red;
    }
}   

PlayerLife : PlayerBase
{
    void Start()
    {
        Cube.Color = base.Color;
    }
}   


PlayerController : PlayerBase
{
    void Start()
    {
        Foo.Color = base.Color;
    }
}
```

As I can see, childs Start are initialized before the start of my parent.
Therefore, Color is null (black with 0 alpha).

How can I use a property of my parent, initialized in his start() with my child class ?

(My first solution was : created a function in PlayerBase to initialise my Color, like this :

```
protected void InitColor()
{
    Color = Color.red;
}
```

And in my child class, I called this function, everytime I needed it.

It's poor and not logic. Because for the PlayerBase class, the color still be black (null))

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

What you can do is make the base class method **virtual** and **override** in the child classes, and then in child classes you can call the `Start` method implementation of base class using `base.Start()` so that the base class code implementation gets executed before child implementation executes:

```
PlayerBase : MonoBehaviour
{
    //Some props
    public Color Color {get; set;}

    protected virtual void Start()  // make it virtual so childs can override
    {
        Color = Color.Red;
    }
}   

PlayerLife : PlayerBase
{
    override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();    // call first base class implementation
        Cube.Color = base.Color;
    }
}   


PlayerController : PlayerBase
{
    override void Start()
    {
        base.Start();    // call first base class implementation
        Foo.Color = base.Color;
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to mark those as protected/public/internal or it won't work.

Comment: This is what I tried, it work but, every child class create an own instance of PlayerBase.
Because, if I do that with Life prop, Life in PlayerLife will be 80 (for example), but in PlayerController, life = 100

Comment: So, if I want to update my Life in my PlayerBase class, the Life in my PlayerLife will not change...

Comment: if you want that way, you need one property in the base class and use it in child classes, that way you will have same life in each child instance and parent class

Comment: This is what you made, no ?
I created a small solution here to make what I want : https://www.sendspace.com/file/lyhh73

Answer (score 1):

Change variable life to static if you want only one copy of it.

```
protected static float Life { get; set; }
```

Comment: Hello,

Thanks for your answer, this is what I did, but for the inheritance logic, is it good ?

Comment: remember one thing, making static will have one copy of this property shared in all instances

Comment: Static Life variable, I don't think is a bad idea assumed that there is one player and with one life. But inheritance is not right here, I think you have attached both scripts (PlayerBase and PlayerLife) to the GameObject. Which is wrong, because when game starts both scripts run and make their instances separately. PlayerBase shouldn't be attached to GameObject.

Comment: Yes, right, PlayerBase, PlayerLife, PlayerController, PlayerAimManager... are on my Player GameObject. So I just delete my PlayerBase on my Player Object and it's done ?

Comment: Yes and also do the same to Update function that you are doing to Start(Make it virtual, override it and in child's update call base.Update). Because now none of Start , Update and FixedUpdate etc functions are going to work, you have to explicitly call them in child classes. This is how inheritance is done in Unity. Important thing, I think you should use Composition or Aggregation here.